# on some devices, ISurfaceComposer captureScreen method cause screen to freeze

Tags: android, surfaceflinger

I am using ISurfaceComposer captureScreen method to create android device screen capture but on some devices the method call causes the entire screen to freeze.
Any idea why is this happening ?
Is SurfaceFlinger locked when the screen capture is in process ?

Comment: `ISurfaceComposer` is not in the Android SDK. Is this for your own ROM mod?

Comment: no. I am creating a process that captures the screen ( for rooted devices)